get 404 for external js file in vue js 3?
i have vue js project and i use adminlte template i set js file like that in my App.vue:
<script>


 export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted(){
console.log(__filename)
const scriptsToLoad = [
  './template/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  './template/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',
  './template/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
  './template/bower_components/morris.js/morris.min.js',
  './template/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
  './template/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js',
  './template/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js',
  './template/bower_components/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js',
  './template/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js',
  './template/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js',
  './template/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js',
  './template/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js',
  './template/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
  './template/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js',
  './template/dist/js/adminlte.min.js',
  './template/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js',
  './template/dist/js/demo.js'
];

scriptsToLoad.forEach(src => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute("src",src);
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
}

}


</script>

but i got this error for all files:
main.js:21
   GET http://localhost:8080/template/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

i put adminlte files in src folder
so what is problme?

It's unknown what's your case, so nothing can be suggested. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . What you showed presumes that template/ contains JS project that needs to be built, and bower_components is supposed to contain the dependencies that are installed with Bower. Check installation instructions that come with the template at least
